# Корневой каталог сайта Python Flask

Tags: flask, root

друзья! Как получить доступ к корневому каталогу простого сайта, который управляется Flask. Структура такая:

```
/website
    /static
        /сss
        /js
    /templates
    routes.py
    __init__.py
test.txt
application.py
config.py
```

Файл config.py

```
import os

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
APP_STATIC = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static')

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-guess'
```

Файл **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

from website import routes
```

В папке templates шаблоны .html легко получают доступ к папке static/css по такому пути

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Если я размещу файл test.txt в папке /static/css/test.txt то могу получить к нему доступ из адресной строки my-syte.com/static/css/test.txt.
То же происходит, если файл размещен в папке /static/test.txt - путь доступа работает my-syte.com/static/test.txt.
Таким образом, я логично предположил, что если поместить файл в папку /website, то я могу получить доступ к нему по адресу my-syte.com/test.txt. Но браузер отвечает ошибкой доступа "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."
Вероятно, нужна какая-то дополнительная запись конфигурации root-папки сайта, или моя запись неверная. Путь к корневой папке нужен для верификации разных сервисов (Google, mail и т.д.). Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39566101/5909792

Comment: Фласк занимается обработкой запросов согласно настройкам роутинга. По умолчанию прописана раздача файлов из каталога static - вот и раздаёт. Все остальные роуты вам нужно прописывать самостоятельно (как - есть в любом учебнике про Flask)

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался. Приложение было размещено в учебной среде cs50.io, потому были вопросы. Я разместил приложение на отдельном хостинге. На данный момент я понял, что лучше пользоваться средствами nginx для обслуживания статических файлов, а Flask оставить настройку роутов самого приложения. Теперь мне осталось разобраться в принципах маршрутизации приложения Flask на серверах ngnix )) Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!